# Where can functions be defined

Tags: javascript, scope

Edited: The expression `function foo() {return 20;}, foo()` was meant to be a single argument to `console.log`).

This:

```js
console.log((function foo() {return 20;}, foo()));
```

Doesn't work, I get `ReferenceError` because `foo` has not been defined.

Why?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but you could use an IIFE in this case `console.log((function foo() {return 20;})());`

Answer (score 9):

```
console.log(function foo() {return 20;}, foo());
```

In this code, you are passing a *named* (`foo`) function as an argument to `console.log`. Got it? You've never *declared* function `foo`, you're just passing it as an argument. In javascript a function declaration and a function expression has the same syntax hence the confusion.

That said, passing a *named* (instead of *anonymous*) function is almost always useless. Your code is  equivalent to this:

```
console.log(function () {return 20;}, foo());
```

where `function () {return 20;}` is an anonymous function in contrast to a named one. And anonymous functions are very wide-spread in JS, because again, names in named function expressions are mostly useless.

Comment: *"You never declare function foo, you just passing it as an argument."* - Well said

Comment: What's the purpose of a named function expression?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

I see that you edited the original question. Since you are actually passing only one argument to `console.log()`, I believe in this case the reason that you're getting a ReferenceError is because when you use a comma like that, that function syntax is treated as a function expression rather than a function declaration. So it's a named function, but it's not a declared function and is still out-of-scope for the `foo()` expression.

For more on declarations and statements vs. expressions, see http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html, particularly the section "Function expression versus function declaration".

To be clear, this (on its own line) would be a function declaration:

```
function foo() {return 20;})
```

Whereas this is defining a variable and assigning it to a named function *expression*:

```
const foo = function foo() {return 20;})
```

In your code, you're actually creating a function *expression* even though it may look like it's a function *declaration*.

---

Functions can be defined anywhere that a statement or expression is allowed. So the syntax of your code is valid, but it doesn't work because expressions are scoped to where they are defined. In this case, the second argument has no access to the `foo` function in the first argument. It's similar to how when using `let` or `const`, the variable is inaccessible outside of its block, e.g.:

```
if (someCondition) {
    const foo = () => 20
    console.log(foo())  // works
}
console.log(foo())  // doesn't work: Uncaught ReferenceError: someCondition is not defined
```

So if you need to call a function in an argument to `console.log()`, then you need to declare the outside the `console.log()` statement, for example:

```
function foo() {return 20;}
console.log(foo());
```

Alternatively, as some others have mentioned, you could use an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), because that doesn't try to access the function from the second argument position of `console.log()` (it only involves one argument):

```
console.log((function foo() {return 20;})())
```

...but in practice this is a poor use of an IIFE; there's no point in doing that here.

Answer (score 2):

Each "log" using `console.log` will output the value registered in the scope of which `console.log` is called.

In your case, you are defining a function inside the call of the `console.log`, this named function will only be defined in there. **You'll need to define your function outside of the `console.log`** so you can output its value.

The second parameter will behave like the first one, and will search for a value in the global scope. It has no way to look for the value defined in the first parameter.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can also use an iife and achieve the wanted result, eg:

`console.log((function foo() {return 20;})())`

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu Yes you can, but it's useless because foo is not declared. Write directly `console.log(20)`